# java jstack How many threads run in the same moment?

Tags: multithreading, stack

I run the following code, when I use jstack check thread information, found 100 threads in the runnable state. I know what is the maximum number of CPU thread of execution core * 2, but I'm very confused, even jstack is not instantaneous, why is a runnable thread?Or is not executed by the CPU thread state is runnable.

Has not been thread of execution, his status is also a runnable?

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      new Thread(() -> {
        long last = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
          byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
          FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("");
          while (fileInputStream.read(buf) != -1) {

          }
          fileInputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("read over " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - last) );
      }, "name" + i).start();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Simply because a thread exists does not necessarily mean it's currently running.

Comment: yes, yes, I wrong, thread state has nothing to do with the CPU. @G